# NoClassDefFoundError in a provider jar when using a class from org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.broker.util

Tags: java, jar, keycloak

I am writing an Authenticator provider for keycloak, that I package as a `.jar`.
As soon as it uses a class from keycloak-services, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.
I get the same error when the provider is deployed via "`mvn wildfly:deploy`".

I must be missing something, but I rarely do java code and I am clueless at this point.

I defined the dependencies in pom.xml, and tried both 'provided' and 'compile' as scope:

```xml
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi-private</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>3.1.4.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I get the error as soon as I add the following code to the authenticate function:

```java
    AuthenticationSessionModel authSession = context.getAuthenticationSession();
    SerializedBrokeredIdentityContext serializedCtx =
        SerializedBrokeredIdentityContext.readFromAuthenticationSession(
            authSession, "BROKERED_CONTEXT");
```

The error I get:

```
20:05:03,844 ERROR [org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler] (default task-6) Uncaught server error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/keycloak/authentication/authenticators/broker/util/SerializedBrokeredIdentityContext
```

Comment: When you get NoClassDefFoundError, it means that at compile time, the class was found, but at runtime the class isn't there. This can occur in a number of ways. Of those, two are: different code versions, different source vs. execute classpath.

Comment: This I get, but I defined the provider as documented, and I have no control on the classpath (that I know of). The class must be present since it is used by builtin providers. The keycloak version is the same at compile time and runtime, and I think the java version is the same (would my .jar be loaded at all if it was not the case ?).

Answer (score 26):

Because wildfly isolates the classloaders, I had to declare the dependencies in the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file.

To do that, I added the following code to my pom.xml file:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Dependencies>org.keycloak.keycloak-services</Dependencies>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

(The solution was given to me on the keycloak user list: https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2019-September/019108.html)

Comment: Thank you, it saved me a lot of time and effort.

Comment: Also works when using jar-with-dependencies with maven-assembly-plugin:
<configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                            </descriptorRefs>
                            <archive>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Dependencies>org.keycloak.keycloak-services</Dependencies>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>

Comment: I had a similar error on Quarkus distribution, and got it solved by adding the missing jar files to the "providers" folder, in the keycloak home path

Answer (score 2):

To do the same thing as @Christophe de Vienne using Gradle:

build.gradle

```
configurations {
    bundleLib
}

dependencies {
    //...
    compile "org.keycloak:keycloak-services:$keycloakVersion"
}

jar {
    from {
        configurations.bundleLib.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Dependencies'   : "org.keycloak.keycloak-services"
        )
    }
}
```